# introduction of gps-sdr-sim

Tags: gps, gnuradio, usrp

I tried gps-sdr-sim for NI USRP-2920.
At the first, I cloned gps-sdr-sim in github.
The next, I typed 'gcc gpssim.c -lm -03 -o gps-sdr-sim' in terminal.
As a result, gps-sdr-sim was created in gps-sdr-sim directory.
At the last, I typed 'gps-sdr-sim -e brdc3540.14n -g triumphv3.txt'.
But, it is displayed 'command in not found' in terminal.

I can't understand this reason.
Could you tell me any advices?
Thank you.

Comment: you need to specify the  path to gps-sdr-sim, since it's not part of the directories that your shell looks into to find executables. I.e. `./gps-sdr-sim -e brdc3540.14n -g triumphv3.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for Mr. Marcus Müller.
Your comment is correct answer.
As a result, I could transmit GPS signal by USRP.